# Regular Expression to match parentheses and brackets for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex that matches text inside parentheses:

```
/\([^\)]*?\)/g
```

I want to be able to match both parentheses and brackets so it will detect both parentheses and brackets in a string so I can color it.

This should be the string:

```
The (quick) brown [fox]
```

I want to color `(quick)` and `[fox]` so I need the regex to match both parentheses and brackets.

Thanks.

Comment: How about `/[(\[][^\)\]]*?[)\]]/g`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work:

```
/\([^)]*\)|\[[^\]]*\]/g;
```

Try it out below:

```js
var str = "The (quick) brown [fox]";

var re = /\([^)]*\)|\[[^\]]*\]/g;

str.match(re).forEach(function(m) {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', m + '<br>');
});
```

**[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gB1nC0/2)**

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thank you for your input. Can you provide an example where I need to specify the lazy operator? I can't think of one.

Comment: it's not difficult. `"The (quick) brown [fox] The (quick) brown [fox] The (quick) brown [fox] The (quick) brown [fox]"`. Are you still hesitating about "lazy" operator?

Comment: Secondly, test this input string `var str = "The (function test(quick){ body }) brown [fox]";`. What if one needs that function definition within "parent" brackets?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I understand your concern. Without the OP having further specify the use case, I won't add more specificity to the regex as it may be unnecessary. Concerning your string, I've tested it and the lazy operator doesn't seem to be needed. (Check out the updated Regex101!). Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I use, based on popular [xregexp](https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp) package by Steve Levithan.
Note that **left** and **right** params are regx expressions so the solution can handle more difficult scenarios. Solution correctly handles nested parenteses as welll. Refer to http://xregexp.com/api/#matchRecursive for more details and options.

```
const XRegExp = require('xregexp');

// test: match ${...}
matchRecursive('${a${b}c} d${x} ${e${}${f}g}', '\\${', '}').forEach(match => {
    console.log(match.innerText);
});

/* yields:
a${b}c
x
e${}${f}g
*/

interface XRegExpPart { start: number; end: number; name: string; value: string; }
export interface XRegExpMatch { index: number; outerText: string; innerText: string; left: string; right: string; }

export function replaceRecursive(text: string, left: string, right: string, replacer: (match: XRegExpMatch) => string, flags: string = 'g', escapeChar?: string): string {
    const matches: XRegExpMatch[] = matchRecursive(text, left, right, flags, escapeChar);
    let offset: number = 0;

    for (const match of matches) {
        const replacement = replacer(match);
        if (replacement == match.outerText) continue;
        text = replaceAt(text, match.index + offset, match.outerText.length, replacement);
        offset += replacement.length - match.outerText.length;
    }
    return text;
}

export function matchRecursive(text: string, left: string, right: string, flags: string = 'g', escapeChar?: string): XRegExpMatch[] {
    // see: https://github.com/slevithan/xregexp#xregexpmatchrecursive
    // see: http://xregexp.com/api/#matchRecursive
    const parts: XRegExpPart[] = XRegExp.matchRecursive(text, left, right, flags, { valueNames: [null, 'left', 'match', 'right'], escapeChar: escapeChar });
    const matches: XRegExpMatch[] = [];
    let leftPart: XRegExpPart;
    let matchPart: XRegExpPart;

    for (const part of parts) {
        // note: assumption is made that left, match and right parts occur in this sequence
        switch (part.name) {
            case 'left':
                leftPart = part;
                break;
            case 'match':
                matchPart = part;
                break;
            case 'right':
                matches.push({ index: leftPart!.start, innerText: matchPart!.value, outerText: leftPart!.value + matchPart!.value + part.value, left: leftPart!.value, right: part.value });
                break;
            default:
                throw new Error(`Unexpected part name: '${part.name}'.`);
        }
    }

    return matches;
}

export function replaceAt(string: string, index: number, length: number, replacement: string): string {
    return string.substr(0, index) + replacement + string.substr(index + length);
}
```

Comment: What question are you anwsering? OP didn't talk about nested structure.

Comment: Hi did not specify text inside parentheses cannot contain matched or unmatched parentheses. Solution I propose can handle such case - unmatched parentheses has to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

`\(\w+\)|\[\w+\]`

You can test it [here](http://regexr.com/3ddn5).

Comment: `\w` will break special characters like á or ñ.

Answer (score 0):

This regex

```
/[(\[][^\)\]]*?[)\]]/g
```

should do it for you. It would allow mixing of brackets like this though.

```
The (quick] brown [fox)
```

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dL3jP3/2).

Comment: how about this string `"The (quick] brown [fox)"` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest What about it? As said, it'll match all words (or phrases) inside brackets, any of `[`, `(` and `]`, `)`.

Comment: it will mix it, without determining which one wrapped only with brackets, and witch - with parenthesis only

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Exactly. That's why I stated the flaw in the answer - "It would allow mixing of brackets like ..." ;)