# Regex for brackets matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I a using the current regex `/(?:^|[^\/\\])\[([\w\s-]*)($|\[)/` to match when user starts to enter chars and enter [some tex, to match this. When he closes it stops the match.

The problem is that i added condition in front, the `?:` and if he enter `\[` or `/[`, i am not going to match it.

Well but, if he has something like `[text][bla` - in this i will match the previous `]` bracket and the string will be `][bla`, but i don't want this. If he enters `[test] [car` - this will match the space in front and will be `_[car` - `_` is space.

I want from both to match only from opening bracket to, not before it. Do you guys have some ideas. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried some simple lib for bracket parsing?

Comment: i want it with regex

Comment: take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205344/regular-expression-to-match-parentheses-and-brackets-for-javascript

Comment: Not quite sure why the regex has to be so complicated if it's just matching simple bracket contents.  Why doesn't this work for you?: `/\[([^\]]*)\]/g`

Comment: as i said i. want to have an escaping, https://imgur.com/a/f0kk9xe this isnt escaping

Comment: and also your logic is different, read the question

Comment: i want something like this but to not match the both ][

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/U3Vidii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not totally clear, but if I understand you correctly, you would like to detect pairs of `[` and `]` angle brackets, but skip over `/` and `\` escaped angle brackets like `\]` and `/]`, correct?

So `[aaa]` would be one pair, `[bbb/[ccc/]ddd]` another, and `[eee\[fff\]ggg]` another.

Here is how you can parse that with three regular expressions:

```js
var str = 'Test [1st], and [2nd\\[with\\]escapes], and [3nd/[more/]escapes][4thNoSpace] text';
var re = /(\[[^\]]*\])/g;
var result = str
.replace(/([\\\/])\]/g, '$1\x01') // replace escapes with tokens
.replace(re, function(m, p1) {    // process bracket pairs
  return '<b>' + p1 + '</b>';
})
.replace(/(.)\x01/g, '$1\]');     // restore escapes from tokens

console.log('before: ' + str);
console.log('result: ' + result);
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', result);
```

So, this input:
`Test [1st], and [2nd\[with\]escapes], and [3nd/[more/]escapes][4thNoSpace] text`

...produces this output:
`Test <b>[1st]</b>, and <b>[2nd\[with\]escapes]</b>, and <b>[3nd/[more/]escapes]</b><b>[4thNoSpace]</b> text`

Explanation:

- the test input string has 4 angle brackets pairs, two of which have escaped brackets, one follows another without a space
- the first regex replaces escaped angle brackets with with a temporary token, so that the second regex does not trip over escaped angle brackets
- the second regex identifies proper angle bracket pairs
- the third regex restored the tokens back to the escaped angle brackets
- the resulting text adds bold tags around the angle bracket pairs to indicate proper parsing

In the future it would be helpful to specify example input strings, and expected output for each input.